# WSO2 inherit tenant policies

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 identity server with multi tenant support enabled, already i defined my policies and roles for access control interactions, my question is, how can i inherit my roles and policies to new tenant created in base to demanded of new users tenant?

Answer (score 1):

No, each tenant in WSO2 products is separated in the data level. So you can not inherit role/ policy to the new tenant